# Finding corresponding text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spread sheet which includes Town_name, Road_Name, Survey_status (Complete, WIP, Pending), i need to check the status of survey and put overall status against the town_name in another spread sheet.

[image: Spread sheet 1]

[image: Spread sheet 2]

[Please check sheet](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zQP_J5YuZI_UG73cdmJkQC8oGCVPe9Xx)

Here, if any town is under WIP (Work in Progress) then the overall status should be WIP, if all Done, then it should be mentioned as Done.
There are about 1000 odd towns and it is becoming difficult to manually check and put the status.

Is there any formula that can help me out from this type of situation.

Comment: In your spread sheet you show B2 being marked as complete even though there are 5 in the list that are `Pending`  Should that be `Pending` or `Complete`?

Answer (score 1):

Use COUNTIFS:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Spreadsheet_1!A:A,A2,Spreadsheet_1!C:C,"WIP"),"WIP",IF(COUNTIFS(Spreadsheet_1!A:A,A2,Spreadsheet_1!C:C,"Pending"),"Pending",IF(COUNTIFS(Spreadsheet_1!A:A,A2,Spreadsheet_1!C:C,"Done"),"Complete","No Entry")))
```

[image]